# r loop for filtering through each column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame like this:
    [gene expression data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1eG3.png)
Assuming column name as different samples and row name as different genes.
Now I want to know the number of genes left after I filter from each column with a number
For example,

```
sample1_more_than_5 <- df[(df[,1]>5),]
sample1_more_than_10 <- df[(df[,1]>10),]
sample1_more_than_20 <- df[(df[,1]>20),]
sample1_more_than_30 <- df[(df[,1]>30),]
```

Then,

```
sample2_more_than_5 <- df[(df[,2]>5),]
sample2_more_than_10 <- df[(df[,2]>10),]
sample2_more_than_20 <- df[(df[,2]>20),]
sample2_more_than_30 <- df[(df[,2]>30),]
```

But I don't want to repeat this 100 times as I have 100 samples.
Can anyone write a loop for me for this situation? Thank you

Comment: Can you make this a [mcve]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution using two loops that calculates, by each sample (columns), the number of genes (rows) that have a value greater than the one indicated in the `nums` vector.

```
#Create the vector with the numbers used to filter each columns
nums<-c(5, 10, 20, 30)

#Loop for each column
resul <- apply(df, 2, function(x){
  #Get the length of rows that have a higher value than each nums entry
  sapply(nums, function(y){
    length(x[x>y])
  })
})

#Transform the data into a data.frame and add the nums vector in the first column
resul<-data.frame(greaterthan = nums,
                  as.data.frame(resul))
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much. Have a wonderful day!

Answer (score 3):

We can  loop over the columns and do this  and create the grouping with `cut`

```
lst1 <- lapply(df, function(x) split(x, cut(x, breaks = c(5, 10, 20, 30))))
```

or `findInterval`  and then `split`

```
lst1 <- lapply(df, function(x) split(x, findInterval(x,  c(5, 10, 20, 30))))
```

---

If we go by the way the objects are created in the OP's post, there would be 100 * 4 i.e. 400 objects (100 columns) in the global environment.  Instead, it can be single `list` object.

The objects can be created, but it is not recommended

```
v1 <- c(5, 10, 20, 30)
v2 <- seq_along(df)
 for(i in v2) {
     for(j in v1) {
      assign(sprintf('sample%d_more_than_%d', i, j), 
               value = df[df[,i] > j,, drop = FALSE])
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The for loop worked. But for the lst1 one, it didn't generate the number that larger than 30. Only the number of genes which have 5-10, 10-20, 20-30 sequencing reads are given.

Comment: @JinyongHuang i think you need to have `Inf` at the end i.e. `c(5, 10, 20, 30, Inf)`